# Traceback on discord.py

Tags: python, import, discord

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "path_to_folder\Python-Discord-Bot\src\python\main.py", line 4, in <module> from discord import File ImportError: cannot import name 'File' from 'discord' (unknown location)`

I was making an profile command and i finished it was all ok (i imported Pillow and others)
but when i finished importing, the await ctx.send(file=discord.File(file)) was getting error that can't import file from discord.py

Is there an solution or something? If it's even possible to import File from discordpy -_-

Comment: Do you have a file of your own named `discord.py`?

Comment: Hello! No, this would glitch discord.py. The (only) file that i have is main.py!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you installed the discord.py module to the version of Python that you are using?